# Configuring VPN along with ISP credentials

Tags: vpn, isp

I have an Archer c2 Tp-link router and am trying to add VPN .Most of the directions online instruct me to change the credentials on my WAN settings page to that of the VPN settings however if i do that i lose connectivity to my ISP. Does anybody know of a way to solve this problem. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting up a VPN you do not change your ISP's settings on your router, that would disconnect you from the internet(You even said that). A VPN is a tunnel that uses your internet to give you access to a remote network, or a tunnel to access internet via that other network.

To properly institute this we would need more details, like what VPN service you are trying to use, and do you already have a client software installed, if not, how are you wanting to connect.

The VPN features on the Archer C2 only supports VPN passthrough, which can help optimize the speed of the connection on the VPN. It itself does not create, and is not a client for a VPN. (http://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?81223-VPN-access-Archer-C2)

Comment: If you have found my answer helpful, please select this as the answer. If not, please clarify your question here.